# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I was working with php and mysql and can't seem to insert data into a database.
Here's the error below:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'My Street','A00 1PQ','')' at line 3

```
$username   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $pword      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwd']);
 $fname      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
 $lname      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
 $email      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $telephone  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
 $ad1        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ad1']);
 $ad2        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['street']);
 $ad3        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['town']);
 $pcode      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pcode']);


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","myuser","mypass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("peoplesdb", $con);

//$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[description]);

$sql="INSERT INTO members (username, pword, fname, lname, email, telephone, ad1, ad2, ad3, pcode, status)
VALUES
('$username','$pword','$fname', '$lname', '$email','$telephone','$ad1','$ad2,'$ad3','$pcode')";
```

The data on that line 3 are address3 and post code. Everything seem ok to me, but still can't figure out what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of mysql clearly shows a quoting problem and looking at this line I see a missing ' in your code after `$ad2`

```
('$username','$pword','$fname', '$lname', '$email','$telephone','$ad1','$ad2,'$ad3','$pcode')";
```

Comment: Thanks @HefferWolf, for pointing out the missing single quote character. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a value to insert for status.  You have one more column than you do values.

Comment: Correct. You have 11 insert intos, and only 10 values.

Comment: I know about the missing value- that is an auto increment value, it was delibrately left blank. Thanks anyway, I've solved it. There was a missing ' in the query.

Answer (score 4):

You are forgetting an extra `'` after `'$ad2` but before `,'$ad3'`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the field status, but didn't list it in the VALUES.

Answer (score 0):

Please check a insert query field name is 11.but value is only 10

```
"INSERT INTO members (username, pword, fname, lname, email, telephone, ad1, ad2, ad3, pcode, status)
VALUES
('$username','$pword','$fname', '$lname', '$email','$telephone','$ad1','$ad2,'$ad3','$pcode')";
```